# Field from DB query using get_field('status') is returning NULL

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, null

I am getting `NULL` when I try to display the `'status'` field on the page. when I do a `var_dump` it also displays NULL. Not sure what is wrong.

I am trying to display Text in the image-overlay class.

Every other var is showing without issues.

I have tried status == and status = etc, but nothing seems to work, I must be missing something.

```
<?php
    unset($bed); unset($type); unset($salerent); unset($pricemin); unset($pricemax); unset($status);
    $salerent = 'sale';
    $salerent2 = 'rent';
    $type = 'villa'; $type2='condo'; $type3='house'; $type4='land';
    $status = 'NEW'; $status2='SOLD'; $status3='HOT DEAL';
    $bed = 'all';
    $minprice='0';
    $maxprice='999999999';
    if ($bed=='all') 
    {
        $bed1=1;$bed2=2;$bed3=3;$bed4=4;$bed5=5;
        $bed6=6;$bed7=7;$bed8=8;$bed9=9;$bed10=10;
    }
    if ($salerent=='rent'){
        $p0text="Price (per month)";
        $p1text="0 - 10,000";
        $p2text="10,000 - 25,000";
        $p3text="25,000 - 40,000";
        $p4text="40,000 - 80,000";
        $p5text="80,000+";  
    }
    else{
        $p0text="Price";
        $p1text="0 - 3 mill";
        $p2text="3 - 6 mill";
        $p3text="6 - 10 mill";
        $p4text="10 - 20 mill";
        $p5text="20+ mill"; 
    }
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include( get_template_directory() . '/menu.php'); ?>  
    <!-- Main-->
    <main>
    <!-- Main Container-->
    <div class='container '>
        <div class="row" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <h1 class="hometitle"><span style="font-size:1.1em; color:red; position:absolute; margin-left:-4px; margin-top:-19px;  transform: rotate(25deg);">/</span>star property<br /><span class="mainsub"> Villas, Condos &amp; Houses for Sale &amp; Rent in Hua Hin</span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 center-on-small-only text-center">
                <div class="row searchbox">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <form id="searchurl" method="POST" action="http:// .com/search-result/?">
                            <span class="filter">Search:</span>
                            <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="salerent" name="salerent">
                                <option value="sale" <?php if($salerent=='sale'){echo "selected";}?>>Sale</option>
                                <option value="rent" <?php if($salerent=='rent'){echo "selected";}?>>Rent</option>
                            </select>

                            <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="type" name="type">
                                <option value="villa" <?php if ($type=='villa'){echo "selected";}?>>Villa</option>
                                <option value="condo" <?php if ($type=='condo'){echo "selected";}?>>Condo</option>
                                <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='house'){echo "selected";}?>>House</option>
                                <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='land'){echo "selected";}?>>Land</option>
                                <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='commercial'){echo "selected";}?>>Commercial</option>
                            </select>

                            <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="bed" name="bed">
                                <option value="all">Bedrooms</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                            </select>

                            <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="pricerange" name="pricerange">
                                <option id="p0" value="all"><?php echo $p0text;?></option>
                                <option id="p1" value="1"><?php echo $p1text;?></option>
                                <option id="p2" value="2"><?php echo $p2text;?></option>
                                <option id="p3" value="3"><?php echo $p3text;?></option>
                                <option id="p4" value="4"><?php echo $p4text;?></option>
                                <option id="p5" value="5"><?php echo $p5text;?></option>
                            </select>
                            <input class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 mysearch" type="text" id="searchid" name="searchid" placeholder="#ID/Project" />
                            <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('searchurl').submit();" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">SEARCH</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
       </div>



       <div class="row zero col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
           <h2 style="width:100%; margin:0.8em 0 0.8em 0;">New Listings:<br /><span class="sub"> Properties for Sale &amp; Rent in Hua Hin</span></h2>
       </div>  
       <div class="row" style="padding:0; margin:0;">

           <?php
               $args = array(
                   'posts_per_page'    => 6,
                   'post__in' => array(22094, 16782, 20898, 19838, 22150, 1442, 1794),
                   'post_type'     => 'post',
                   'no_paging' => true,
                   'order' => DESC,
                   'cat'           => 2,
               );
               // query
               $the_query = new Wp_Query( $args ); 
           ?>

           <ul id="starlistings" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 row" >
               <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="float:left; ">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 listingframe" >
                                <div class="row" style="background-color:#77c0ff" "padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">
                                    <div class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                        <a class="listingslink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="padding-top:0.8em;">
                                    <div class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12" class="zero">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image_1'); ?>" class="w-100" alt="<?php the_field('image_1_alt'); ?>" title="<?php the_field('area_project'); ?> <?php $type = get_field('type'); if ($type=='Villa') echo 'House'; else { the_field('type');} ?> for <?php the_field('sale_or_rent'); ?> in Hua Hin">**<div class="image-overlay"><?php $status = get_field('status'); if ($status=='NEW') echo 'NEW ARRIVAL'; else { the_field('status');} ?></div>**</a>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center listingsdivider col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                <span>
                                    <span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0;">ID #<?php the_field('property_id'); ?></span>
    <span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0;"><?php $price = get_field('Price'); echo number_format($price, 0, '', ','); ?> baht<?php $saleorrent = get_field('sale_or_rent'); if($saleorrent=='Rent'){echo ' ';} ?> 
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="listingsicons"  style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0.5em;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/house.png" alt="house" style="height:12px; width:auto; margin:-4px 8px 0 0; padding:0; opacity:0.7" /><?php the_field('living_space'); ?> SQM</span>
                                    <span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0.5em;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/beds.png" alt="bedrooms" style="height:12px; width:auto; margin:-2px 4px 0 -3px; padding:0; opacity:0.6" /><?php the_field('bedrooms'); ?> Beds</span>
                                    <span style="padding:5px 0 5px 0.5em; "><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/bathrooms.png" alt="bathrooms" style="height:15px; width:auto; margin:-2px 6px 0 2px; padding:0; opacity:0.6;" /><?php the_field('bathrooms'); ?> Baths</span>
                                </span>

                                <div style="background-color: white; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px"><span><?php $excerpt = wp_trim_words( get_field('property_description' ), $num_words = 10, $more = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">... more</a>' ); echo $excerpt; ?></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly pass in the post id as second parameter? (And `if ($status='NEW')` is of course definitively wrong, that is an _assignment_, not a comparison.)

Comment: Yes, I have passed the post id and the listing id etc and they all work. But as soon as I add status == 'NEW' it displays NULL, I think the code is correct but would appreciate any advice, from people cleverer than me.

Comment: I have no idea what you even mean by that. Where did you “add” status == 'NEW'? Please update your code to show what you currently have. _“and they all work”_ - so what and where exactly is _not_ working now? It is really rather hard to tell what your actual problem is here.

Comment: I have updated the code. The problem is in the image-overlay class or in the status var, when I do a var_dump of the status var it displays NULL, and I am not sure why. as all other vars display the data from the DB.

Comment: And _where_ did you attempt to dump it …? Do a `var_dump(get_field('status'));` inside your loop, that verifies without a doubt whether _this call_ did manage to read the value correctly, or not.

Comment: I added the var_dump inside the loop, and all posts displayed NULL, This website was not written by me, so I am trying to fix the inherited problems. I have also noted that they are using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. which could be the issue....

Comment: `get_field` is a function provided _by_ the ACF plugin, if that wasn’t activated, you would not have this function available in the first place. Did you try to pass in the post id, and that did not work either? Then most likely you do not actually have the meta data stored in the first place, that you think you do. var_dump the result of `get_fields` (plural), that shows you _all_ ACF meta data stored for a specific post.

Comment: I have looked in the database, and see that the field is called "status" no quotation marks, abd they have values e.g. NEW, SOLD etc but I can not get those values to display on the php page. I feel I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved the problem.

And I hope this will help anyone with the same issue.

When adding a field in wp-admin to the Advanced Custom Fields field group.

Make sure you change the "Return Value" to Value.

Label and Both/Array do not work with get_field or the_field.

Hope this helps someone.